# How to create a custom HttpHeaders

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I do this:

```
@GetMapping("hello")
String hello(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    return "hello";
}
```

`headers` has all the headers. I'd like to create a class that inherits from `HttpHeaders` in order to add new properties:

```
class CustomHttpHeaders extends HttpHeaders {
    public String getCustomHeader() { ... } 
}
```

But if I do:

```
@GetMapping("hello")
String hello(@RequestHeader CustomHttpHeaders headers) {
    return "hello";
}
```

it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure why you would need that.. but would a wrapper class do the trick?

Comment: `HttpHeaders` is just a multi-value map. It doesn't make much sense to extend it.

Comment: https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/khoubyari/example/api/rest/HotelController.java

Answer (score 0):

In this case you, as you can add headers to the request as you wish, there isn't really a need to extend the class. Internally, the headers are modeled using a map, allowing you to add custom `<K, V>` pairs very easily.

So, what you should do is to add the custom parameters from where the request is fired, the client-side (e.g: angular client, cURL etc), and server-side you can map the headers with the same `HttpHeaders` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we managed to do:

```
public class CustomHttpHeadersArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return CustomHttpHeaders.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = webRequest.getHeaderNames(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String headerName = iterator.next();
            String headerValue = webRequest.getHeader(headerName);
            if (headerValue != null) {
                map.put(headerName, headerValue);
            }
        }
        return new CustomHttpHeaders(map);
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
class MethodArgumentResolversConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new CustomHttpHeadersArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```